# Can one construct a homeomorphism with noncompact periodic point set?

Tags: dynamical-systems

Can one construct a compact metric space $X$, and a homeomorphism $f\in \text{Homeo}(X)$, such that $f$ has noncompact periodic point set?
I am trying to find a homeomorphism on a cylinder $S^1\times [0,1]$, but not succeeded yet. Looking forward to your brilliant answer. Thanks

**Here are some of my attemptations**

Let $f\in\text{Homeo}(S^1\times [0,1])$, which sends $(x,y,h)$ to $(-x,-y, g(h))$, i.e the antipodal map on the circle, then lift $g(h)$, so it suffices to find a $g:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ which is surjective,continuous  and has dense periodic points (or just fixed points is Okay, I guess).

Because no matter whether $g$ is a homeomorphism, $f$ is a bijective continuous map, thus in this case, a homeomorphism, if the periodic points of $g$ is dense in $[0,1]$, but not the whole interval, we can deduce that the periodic points set of $f$ is not even closed, thus a noncompact one, so now the problem is to construct that peculiar $g$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $x\to 2 x \mod 1.$ (think of it as a homeomorphism of $S^1$). Then, every rational number with odd denominator is a periodic point.

Comment: nice answer，thank you very much ！

Comment: My pleasure....